# Child element top value increased after adding a new child

Tags: html, css, positioning

This is how i designed the layout for my header

```
<div id="DivHeader">
<div id="DivTop">
</div>
<div id="DivBottom">
</div>
</div>
```

Initially i had set the top property for the `DivBottom` as 35px.At that time i did not have `DivTop`.
 So now, after adding it, the top for the `DivBottom` has been calculated from the new child(DivTop) as `DivTop's height` + `DivBottom's top`. As a result the layout got collapsed like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/3u3gz/). I need to place `DivTop` without affecting the `DivBottom's Top`, Any ideas.?

[Note : I did not use absolute positioning for my divs, Because in that case margin:0 auto wont work.]

Answer (score 0):

You're using **relative positioning**, for which this is the expected behavior. See the [W3 on relative positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#relative-positioning):

> Once a box has been laid out according to the normal flow or floated, it may be shifted relative to this position. This is called relative positioning.

So if you insert something above a relatively positioned element, it will first position according to the "normal flow", and then be repositioned according to your CSS.

You'll need to change the `position` to another value if you want the behavior you specified.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use absolute positioning:

```
#first
{
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-5px; /* half the width value */
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3u3gz/1/

Comment: well, is it good to hard code on properties like margins.?, in future, if we change its width, then simultaneously we have to change its margin by recalculating it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see why not.